# reject queries based on specific client_app_name and nt_username

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

With a surge of applications that can be used to pull information, my sql server is constantly getting tapped, and there are a couple of users that keeps running refresh. Is there a way to reject query based on specific client_app_name and nt_username? 
Alternatively, is there a way to add the combination of the user and the app to security to decline access to SQL? i.e. Approve the user access if client_appname is excel but decline if the appname is 'Mashup Engine'.

Comment: Does something like `exec sp_revokelogin 'domain\loginname'` work for you?

Comment: that revoke's the users entire access, I'm fine with him accessing, just not through that specific app...

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is [resource governance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx). With it you can restrict the resources a user can consume. This way the users can refresh as much as they like, but they won't be able to consume the server resources, their queries will instead slow down as they are exhausting the allowed resources. Other users will still be able to run queries at full speed.

The assignment of users to resource groups ('pools') is based on a [classification function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510208.aspx) run at login time, and this function can consider user name, application name, workstation name, client IP etc.